# convert nvarchar to int

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in access linked to SQL.I am doing a query where I am using a field named comment from this table.
The field is designed in SQL as nvarchar(255) . I am writing integers numbers in this field. What I want to do in my query is to convert this field from nvarchar to int so I can use the SUM function.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options.

- CBool—Converts a value to a Boolean data type.
- CDate—Converts a value to a Date data type.
- CInt—Converts a value to an Integer data type.
- CStr—Converts a value to a String data type.
- CVar—Converts a value to a Variant data type.

**Syntax**

- CBool(expression)
- CByte(expression)
- CCur(expression)
- CDate(expression)
- CDbl(expression)
- CDec(expression)
- CInt(expression)
- CLng(expression)
- CSng(expression)
- CStr(expression)
- CVar(expression)

**Converting to an Integer Data Type**

The CInt function takes a numeric or string value and converts it to an Integer data type. The argument is required and needs to represent a value within the range of -32,678 to 32,767. If the argument contains a decimal, Access rounds to the next whole number. A value of .5 or higher is rounded up; anything lower is rounded down. Some examples of CInt functions follow:

```
Dim MyDouble, MyInt
MyDouble = 2345.5678    ' MyDouble is a Double.
MyInt = CInt(MyDouble)    ' MyInt contains 2346.
```

IN SQL, you could use CAST.

```
SELECT
   CAST([Column] AS INT) AS [Column Name]
FROM [Table]
WHERE ...
```

Or, if you wanted to SUM off the SQL query.

```
SUM(CAST([Column] AS INT)) AS [Column Name]
```

Comment: using INT function in access solved the issue , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should store the data in SQL Server as an `INT` field, instead of a `VARCHAR(255)` field?

If you did that, you wouldn't need to make *any* conversions in Access.

Having said that, if you don't want to make changes to the SQL Server database, you can use VB's CInt(field) in Access queries to convert numbers stored as a string into integers.  Be aware this approach will fail if there are *any* non-numeric values stored in the varchar field.

Comment: I don't want to make any changes from SQL side.Only from access side.